# rubygems/util (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

While building SWIFT program on IOS jenkins agent, I am receiving rubygems/util load error from gems file.

does it require any configuration to provide the rubygems/util module ?

unicode-display_width-1.3.2/lib/unicode/display_width/index.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/util (LoadError)